# How to reference an entity by id in a request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm setting up a Spring Boot application, I've already set up entities and connected to a database and now I want to implement saving data from the rest API. Say I have entities like this

```
@Entity
class A {
   ...
   private String name;
   @OneToOne
   private B b; 
   ...
}
```

and I want to be able to send this post "A" creation request when B with id 1 exists. The result of this request would be that A is linked to B.

```
{
   "name":"name Of A"
   "B": {
      "id":1
   }
}
```

Is this possible with the tools given by Spring Boot or is this some not the traditional way of doing things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not understand your question, actually if you just return your entity `A` from a `@RestController` it will parse it properly to JSON as your example, are you having some issue with that?

Comment: I send a given payload and try to save the entity. Hibernate says that the given entity is detached and cannot be saved

Comment: This happens because indeed you do not have either A or B on Hibernate's context after serialization, you should either find the reference as mentioned by madz or fetch the whole entity in the database. I do not recommend you to use database entities directly for serialization, you should be using a DTO instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is not any built in solution to simply map that json to an entity to be saved directly by repository.

You need to use `@RequestBody` for the A argument in the rest controller and then manually use `entityManager.getReference(id_of_b)` to set B entity of A. Then you can use `repository.save` ...

If you want to make it better, you need to write your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and implement and register `StdDesrializer` of `Jackson` to determine `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` relations and then get the id of relation by Jackson and set it by `entityManager.getReference(id_of_b)` as mentioned above.

This way the resulting entity would be ready to be saved directly by repository.